# Members upload photos into their own restricted subdirectory?

Tags: assets

Can this be done, including blockage to other (members) sub directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been waiting for this too, this was possible with a plugin in EE1. You might be better off with Channel Images. With Channels Images people only see their own uploads as standard behavior. Upload is direct through the field, there is no in between library access. People can remove images if they can access their own entries.

Another advantage is that images are deleted with the entries.